# How to delete Custom Table View Cell from the TableView of my ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In one of my ViewControllers, I added a tableview as a subview.

In this tableView I made implemented custom table view cell, which contains a remove button init.

So, when I clicked the remove, the data related is deleted, but the row in the tableview remains, it will disappear, when I reload my APP.

Can anyone help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this method from [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a):

```
- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

The index path is the index of the row to remove.